# How to redirect subdomains to https main domain in apache

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have some site `example.biz`. I redirect all http request to https, but how redirect with subdomains(Excluding one host that is in a different configuration file)? I need something like this:  If i write `bla-bla.example.biz` i must redirected to `example.biz`. But if `ololo.bla-bla.example.biz` - error. And all this redirection must be to https. To all this, I can not add `*.example.biz` to `ServerAlias`, because i have another site `adm.example.biz`. Now If I write something like `any.example.biz`, i left on the home page.

Config of example.com:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin i@example.com
        ServerName example.biz
        ServerAlias www.example.biz
        UseCanonicalName On
        DocumentRoot /var/www/example/webapps
        LogLevel warn
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
        RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/example-error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/example-access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

https config:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
        <VirtualHost _default_:443>
                ServerAdmin i@example.com
                ServerName example.biz
                ServerAlias www.example.biz
                UseCanonicalName On
                DocumentRoot /var/www/example/webapps/
                LogLevel warn
                ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/example-error.log
                CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/example-access.log combined

                <Directory />
                        Options FollowSymLinks
                        AllowOverride None
                </Directory>

                <Directory /var/www/rockfutur/webapps/rockfutur/>
                        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                        AllowOverride All
                        Order allow,deny
                        allow from all
                </Directory>
                SSLEngine on
                SSLCertificateFile      /etc/ssl/certs/example.pem
                SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/example.key

                <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
                                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
                </FilesMatch>
                <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
                                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
                </Directory>

                BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-6]" \
                                nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
                                downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
                # MSIE 7 and newer should be able to use keepalive
                BrowserMatch "MSIE [17-9]" ssl-unclean-shutdown

        </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```